# Compare JSON Responses in Script Assertation

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I am attempting to compare two JSON responses from two separate test steps to determine if they are exactly equal to each other (successful case means that they are) using the following Groovy Script:

```
def response1 = context.expand( '${GetPatientProfileById#Response#}' )
def response2 = context.expand( '${GetPatientProfileById#Response2#}' )
log.info(response1)
log.info(response2)
assert response1 == response2
```

How that just always signals a pass and returns the following info:

```
Mon Oct 05 11:41:33 CDT 2015:INFO:
Mon Oct 05 11:41:33 CDT 2015:INFO:
```

What am I missing? I under the impression that response1 and response2 would hold the JSON string value from the response of their respective test steps but I am clearly missing something.

Comment: What class does context.expand return? If it's not a String, then `response1 == response2` is comparing two different objects. Try `response1.toString() == response2.toString()`

Comment: What is `GetPatientProfileById`? **Both** `response1` and `response2` are using the same test step!

Comment: What is `#Response2#`? No such property exists in SoapUI by default!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

responseContent = messageExchange.modelItem.testCase.getTestStepByName("TestStepName").getPropertyValue("response")
slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)

responseContent2 = messageExchange.modelItem.testCase.getTestStepByName("TestStepName2").getPropertyValue("response")
slurperresponse2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)

log.info (slurperresponse)
log.info (slurperresponse2)

assert slurperresponse == slurperresponse2
```

Comment: You're still comparing the **same one** response to itself!

Comment: Agree with SiKing. Could be problem with copy paste.

Comment: arg sorry it was a problem with blind copy-paste, corrected!

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the `response` property of your `test step` called `GetPatientProfileById` due the last `#`.

This is why `context.expand( '${GetPatientProfileById#Response#}' )` is returning blank. To correct it remove the last `#` as follows: `context.expand( '${GetPatientProfileById#Response}' )`.

Also as @SiKing comment note that you're getting the same test step response for your both variables.

Hope this helps,